For the flutter sensor plus package can anyone tell me how the user acceleration is calculated or share the github link with for that respective file
For the flutter sensor plus package can anyone tell me how the user acceleration is calculated or share me the git-hub link with for that respective file
I have been going through the github repo https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/sensors_plus but unable to find the required section

For iOS https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/sensors_plus/sensors_plus/ios/Classes/FPPStreamHandlerPlus.swift
